# How to send message without using command using hikari lightbulb for discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a discord bot, but since discord.py is no longer supported I wanted to make it using hikari lightbulb. I want to send a message to the channel specified by its id, but I didn't found any resources about it. In discord.py it was not a problem, simply:

```
channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
await channel.send(message)
```

How to do similar thing using hikari **without using command**? - the function that sends the message is not called using command.

Answer (score 3):

In hikari you don't even need to waste a call into the cache to get the channel:

```py
bot = hikari.GatewayBot("TOKEN HERE")
await bot.rest.create_message(channel_id, message)
```

[documentation](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/rest.html#hikari.impl.rest.RESTClientImpl.create_message)